# Blocked Host error while trying to access my app which is inside docker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker

I'm getting this error while trying to open my app which is inside a docker

> Blocked host: xx.xxx.xxx
>   To allow requests to xx.xxx.xxx, add the following to your
>   environment configuration: config.hosts << "xx.xxx.xxx"

and based to another post here I've to edit `config/environments/development.rb` file to add the following line `config.hosts << "xx.xxx.xxx"` the idea here is that I'm running this app from inside a docker and I've searched for this file `development.rb` from inside and outside the docker but I can't find it.

Comment: Where you were looking for? have you found the 'config' folder in your rails application files?

Comment: @ShiraElitzur I fount it at the same path but strangely when I edit it and reboot the server it returns to default file again

Comment: Maybe you changed the configuration only in the container and by rebooting you overrode it? try to access the file and edit it from the host and then restart the container.